# Can you store multiple strings in a Cursor (like an array)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use `Cursors` for `SQLite` databases, and I'm wondering if Cursors work like an `array`, so that you can store multiple `objects` in them?

If so, could someone provide an example of how to take multiple `strings` from a database and store it in to a `cursor`?

I have this code so far, I'm trying to store the data from the result of matching codes from the `code[]` array with a database, then storing the result in the `Cursor`:

```
for (int i=1;i<code.length;i++) {
        cursor = myDataBase.query("codes", new String[]{"description"}, ("code = '" + code[i] + "'" ), null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Thanks.!!

Comment: "I'm wondering if Cursors work like an array, so that you can store multiple objects in them" -- not really. In the context of a SQLite database, `Cursor` is the result of a database query. You do not "store" things in a `Cursor`. You store things in a database, and retrieve them by means of a `Cursor`.

Comment: You could **imagine** database columns like vectors of values of the same type. In this sense, a column could be **roughly** compared to an array. But even if your cursor contains a single column retrieved from a table, it works in a different way. For instance, it's read-only. And you have to move to a valid record before you can use it (by default, it's positioned on row **-1**).

Answer (score 0):

"Is cursor like arrays" - no they aren't. "Can you store information into cursor" - no you can't "directly" as you do it with arrays (but you can some time update information received from cursor).

To store data into database, you should use SQL `INSERT` statement or if you use ORM you can call save or similar command to store data into the database.

About cursors:

Cursors are a pointer to database memory that created when you are querying data from database. When you create a query to the database, it executes in several "steps". At the first database selecting necessary data from hard disk and storing the result (if it fits) into memory. Then the database server sends to the client a "pointer" called the cursor, which points at the head of this set of rows.

At a client's perspective when your program executes, you don't receive all rows (which may don't fit into your memory either) of the result set, but you receive them one by another and can process as you like.

The process described above is very much simplified so the real process of executing a query is much more complicated. But the good news is that you shouldn't worry about it - database driver and database are managing most of its complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I understand now, but I'm not trying to store data in a database. I'm trying to take data from a DB and store it in an array.